# $\lim_{t\to +\infty}\frac{d}{ds}f(t,s)=g'(s)?$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Supose that $f:(0,\infty) \times (0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is a $C^2((0,\infty) \times (0,\infty))$ function, and
$$\lim_{t\to +\infty}f(t,s)=g(s)$$,
can we conclude that
$$\lim_{t\to +\infty}\frac{d}{ds}f(t,s)=g'(s)?$$
I am trying use the Mean Value Theorem but i cant any argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f:(0,\infty) \times (0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined as $f(t,s)=\frac{\sin(t^2s)}{t}$. Then
$$
\lim_{t\to \infty}f(t,s)=0
$$
but
$$
\lim_{t\to \infty}f_s(t,s)= \lim_{t\to \infty} t \cos(t^2s)
$$
does not exist.

Comment: and supposing that $\lim_{t\to \infty} f_s(t,s)$ exist?

Comment: My feeling is still "no", but I don't have a counterexample up to now. In many examples it is true, so there should be a setting where it is true.